# how to use value for loop in text content in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have textfield value that is populated in by the user.  I want to create my own "tag" of sorts so that when present, I can loop through its return value.

Here is example of content that my be entered by the user:

> my awesome content starts
>
> (-- assets --)
>
> ending portion of my content

I'm thinking a template tag would be used for this do something along the lines of:

```
{{ mycontent|check_if_assets_present }}
```

Then this would print something like:

> my awesome content starts
>
> 1. Asset 1
> 2. Asset 2
> 3. Asset 3
>
> ending portion of my content

How can I accomplish this in a django template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a template tag and then replacing when the character set is encountered:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='add_assets')
def add_assets(composition):
    if '(-- assets --)' in composition.content:

        asset_group = AssetGroup.objects.filter(composition=composition)
        unordered_list_str = asset_group_to_html(asset_group)
        composition.content = composition.content.replace('(-- assets --)', unordered_list_str)

    return composition.content
```